# join("") and replace(/,/g,"") in javascript stop when reaching "<" character in char array - why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, char

I am using the javascript function join("") to convert a character array to a string while simultaneously removing the comma separators between characters.

Most of the time this works exactly as expected - but I have just discovered that it fails if there is a "less than" character (<) in the array.

For example:

```js
var chararray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var string = chararray.join("");

console.log(string);
```

produces the string ABCDE

but in this example it does NOT work as expected

```js
var chararray = ["A", "B", "C", "<", "E"];
var string = chararray.join("");

console.log(string);
```

produces the string ABC  (it stops when it reaches the "<" character)

If I use join() - leaving the comma separators in - it works

```js
var chararray = ["A", "B", "C", "<", "E"];
var string = chararray.join();

console.log(string);
```

produces string A,B,C,<,E

but if I then try to remove the commas using string.replace(/./g, "") I get the same result again - ABC

```js
var chararray = ["A", "B", "C", "<", "E"];
var string = chararray.join();
var outputstring = string.replace(/,/g, "");

console.log(outputstring);
```

Produces string ABC - again stopping at the "<" character.

As far as I know "<" is not a special character in javascript (unless used in a math/compare equation) - so why is it doing this?  It does not do this with any other symbols including >, =, etc.

Comment: Where do you see this output?

Comment: It is working as expected and "A,B,C,<,E" is the output

Comment: I'll take a wild guess that you are seeing the output using [Document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/write) or similar, right?

Comment: BINGO! Yes. Why is working HERE but not in my external script? "document.getElementById().innerHTML" does the same thing - why?  Is there a better function to print out the string - or a way to solve the "<" character issue in Document.write()? And why is this only an issue with the "<" character?

Comment: Because you are writing to the webpage DOM and the browser interprets < as the beginning of an HTML tag.

Comment: Interesting - so why does it display properly on THIS webpage?  What is being done differently?

BTW - I found that window.alert(mystring) prints the full string to the screen.  Why does THAT function display the string properly?

Answer (score 1):

Both [element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and [Document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) (sorry I linked to the portuguese page before) expects to receive a HTML string, because they are meant to modify the document of the page. Because of that, they will always interpret the content as HTML. For example:

```js
document.write(`They can make text transformations like <b>bold</b> and
<i>italic</i>, or even more complex HTML elements like
<input placeholder="input" />. <div id="text"></div>`);

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = `<li><small>The</small>
<span style="color: red">same</span> <big>goes</big> <s>to</s>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML">innerHTML</a>`
```

They will interpret any HTML you input.

Other methods and properties like [HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText), [Console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) and even [Window.alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) you mentioned don't do that. They take and display the text as is, ignoring any HTML.

```js
document.getElementById('text').innerText = `In fact, giving
<b>HTML</b> to these methods will just display the <b>HTML</b> code,
so <big>be aware of that</big>.`;
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: OK, great info.  Thank you!